# What versions of mobile WebKit support JavaScript Workers?

Tags: javascript, mobile, webkit

My Google-fu is failing me. I'm trying to determine what version(s) of mobile WebKit (iOS, Android, Blackberry Torch, etc.) support the HTML5 feature JavaScript Workers. Anyone know for sure?

**EDIT**
I've created [a page that logs whether your browser supports the Worker API](http://segdeha.com/w/workers.html). Please hit it if you have a mobile WebKit device and I'll post a summary after a while. Thanks!

**EDIT II**
I finally got a round tuit and added the ability to see a summary of the results. Same link: http://segdeha.com/w/workers.html

Comment: +1 for the nice online test! You should somehow let people send you their checker functions to test other features, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's results based on my own feature detection tests:

```
var supportsWorkers = !!window.Worker;
```

- iOS 4.0.2: no (simulator)
- iOS 4.0.1: no (simulator)
- iOS 4.0: no
- iOS 3.1.3: no
- iOS 3.0: yes
- iOS 2.2.1: no (iPhone 2G)
- Android 2.2: no (Nexus One and emulator)
- Android 2.1-update1: yes
- Android 2.1: yes
- Android 2.0: yes
- Android 1.6: no
- Android 1.5: no
- BlackBerry 6: yes (tested on BB 9800 Torch)
- webOS 1.3: no (emulator)
- Fennec/1.0b1: yes (emulator)

Some of these were tested on actual devices, and some on the emulator.  The results are kind of interesting.. it looks like it was enabled and then disabled later on both Android and iOS.  Keep in mind this is just a feature test, not an actual functional test.

Comment: How did you do your testing? Do you have a whole mess of devices lying around or just a lot of techie friends? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Update: Current iOS (5.1) does support Web Worker (tested with iPad 2 and the URL linked above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any do yet.

My google-fu also failed.

However, I can tell you that they are not supported in Froyo's webkit browser (Android 2.2).  (According to Modernizr)

Maybe some of the iPhone & BB guys can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone OS 4.1 doesn't support workers (on iPod Touch). What I shame, just as I was going to write a webapp. Tested on actual device.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7"
```